# Passing variables through PHP -> Javascript -> AJAX - Options?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am currently working on a CMS where there are a lot of communications between PHP and JavaScript (+ AJAX). I am having difficulties storing variables all through the flow.

For instance: after login you can select a site to edit. When on click, I store the site_id in a POST-variable. After that I redirect to the pages-overview-page where I read out all my pages from the database by using this site_id.

If I add a page, the following happens:

1.The $_POST['site_id'] is put into javascript by echoing:

```
echo "<script>var siteid =".$_POST['siteid'].";</script>"
```

2.My JavaScript then does an AJAX call:

```
$(".leftpanelinner").on('click','._add-page', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".sortable").load("ajax_scripts/page-actions.php/add_page",{siteID: siteid, callFunction:'add_page' });   
});
```

3.This on it's turn fires an php-script which adds a page to the site with a query to my database and then reloads the main div of my page:

```
public function new_page($iSite_id, $sTemplate, $sTitle, $sMeta, $sCSS, $sJS, $sFavicon, $aContent, $aMenu)
{
    $oPagemodel = new page_model;
    $iPage_id=$oPagemodel->insert_pagemodel($iSite_id, $sTemplate, $sTitle, $sMeta, $sCSS, $sJS, $sFavicon, $aContent, $aMenu);
    return $iPage_id;
}

public function insert_pagemodel($iSite_id, $sTemplate, $sTitle, $sMeta, $sCSS, $sJS, $sFavicon, $aContent, $aMenu)
    {
        $this->set_pagemodel($sTemplate, $sTitle, $sMeta, $sCSS, $sJS, $sFavicon, $aContent, $aMenu);   
        $sSQL = "INSERT INTO `pages` (f_site_id, object) VALUES ('".$iSite_id.', '.serialize($this)."');";
        if (mysql_query($sSQL)) {$this->iID = mysql_insert_id();} else {return false;}
        return $this->iID;

    }
```

Isn't there a simpler way to store a variable through JavaScript/PHP/AJAX or is the above the best way?

Comment: have you considered using `data` in jQuery?

Comment: I haven't. Do I create a hidden HTML element where I save all my necessary information to?

Comment: Exactly.  You can store a hundred different variables on one element, and easily retrieve them.  The element *can* be hidden, but it doesn't have to be.  Because `data` isn't ever visible unless you are viewing the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cookies for this.

```
<?php
    $foo = 'lorem';
    setcookie('the_foo',$foo,time() + (86400 * 7)); 

    echo $_COOKIE['the_foo']; 
?>
```

You can get and set cookies with js as well.

Comment: Is this different from using the _SESSIONS variable? The _SESSIONS variable is also stored as cookie right?

Comment: Yes. SESSION variables are stored on the server only, and cannot be accessed by javascript (unless you make an ajax call to a php script that returns the value of the session). HTTP cookies are stored in the users browser.